# Calculate N date range overlap in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, date

I have an dynamic array :

```
var date = [];

        for(var i=0,len=data_start.length;i<len;i++){
            date[date.length] = data_start[i];
            date[date.length] = data_end[i];
        }
```

So in `i%2 == 0` position i have the start dates and in other the end dates.So for example in position 0 I have a start event and in 1  the end event, so I have to controll that this range not overlap over the others. Array can have 100+ ranges.

Some solution for this?

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting a specific index of array `date`, just use the array's built-in `.push()` method. Like this:

```
var date = [];

for(var i=0, len=data_start.length; i<len; i++){
    date.push(data_start[i]);
    date.push(data_end[i]);
}
```

This way, `date_start[i]` and `date_end[i]` will just append to the end of your `date` array, without worrying about overlapping previously existing values.